# telerik report barcode control add blank page

Tags: telerik, reporting

I have a Telerik report that is working as expected.  The report list items in several pages.

The report consist of several columns displaying items' fields.

Once I add a barcode control to the items' columns, the report begin to produce a blank page after every single page.

I am sure that the barcode control is behind this issue as once I remove the barcode control, things are back to normal.

Even If I add a textbox instead of barcode the report print as expected.

I have tried all the available features to get rid of the added blank page but could not succeed.

Please advise and many thanks

ps. I am using Telerik Reporting Q1 2016

Comment: I'd recommend posting to Telerik's forum as well if you haven't already.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue is related to the barcode.
I have found that the field can grow and cause objects to move around when you don't want them.
I would put the barcode on to another report against the same data to see how wide the actual barcode is. This will help you get an idea as to what Telerik is doing and then come up with a game plan.